# Изменить параметры стиля кода в VS 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, code-style

Когда печатаешь символ '#' VS автоматически убирает все пробелы и делает авто-выравнивание по левому краю. Как это убрать, я не нашёл нужный пункт в параметрах стиля, а всё время выравнивать когда пишешь #pragma omp не хочется.

Comment: вы хотите , чтобы до 
    #pragma omp были пробелы?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Текстовый редактор->с/с++-> стиль кода-> форматирование-> отступ-> позиция директив предпроцессора